# Shuffle a list recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to shuffle a list recursively, that has numbers between `1 - 13`, such that each number in the even indices will be on the right side of the list and the numbers in the odd indices will be on the left side of the new list. 
For example take `l=[1, 13, 10, 1, 5, 2, 5, 3]`.
Function should return: `[1, 10, 5, 5, 13, 1, 2, 3]`. 
Here's my work:

```
def shuffle(arr, start, stop):
   if stop == 0:
       return [arr[stop-1]]
   return [arr[start]] + shuffle(arr, start + 2, stop - 2) + [arr[stop-1]]
```

Note: `start =0 , stop = len(arr)`. (and surely the length of the array is a power of 2).

My code output is `[1, 10, 5, 5, 3, 13, 1, 2, 3]`, I have been trying for hours to get rid of the extra `3` in the middle, but I'm really having a hard time. 
When I wrote the return, I thought about solving a smaller problem, and that's how I usually approach recursive answers, and I am taking the first even number and putting it into the left of the list, then sending the "smaller" list, then putting back the last odd number in the list. 

I would really appreciate any help of how to fix this problem, I'm trying to overcome this problem for hours, and I feel like understanding how to fix this will help me understand recursion more. 
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry if it wasn't clear but I know how to solve it normally, my goal is to solve it recursively.

Comment: by shuffle, do you mean randomly sort?  Or just move?

Comment: Moving it in the way I explained at the start, all numbers that are on even indices (1,10,5,5) in the example would be on the left side of the returned list and the numbers on odd indices will be on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `start` and `stop`, try using a single `index` and use negative indexing to traverse the list from the right side:

```
l=[1, 13, 10, 1, 5, 2, 5, 3]

def shuffle(arr, index=0):
  if index >= len(arr):
    return []
  return [arr[index]] + shuffle(arr, index + 2) + [arr[-1-index]]

print(shuffle(l))
```

This approach only works for lists with an even number of elements, but that should be ok based on what you've told us.

Answer (score 0):

You could partition the list and only recurse for the shuffling of the left and right portions:

```
from random import choice

def shuffle(A,left=None,done=0):
  if left is None:
    A    = A[::2]+A[1::2]   # partition list
    left = len(A[1::2])     # compute left size for recursion
  if done>left:return A     # all shuffled
  if done<left:            
      rLeft  = choice(range(done,left))            # shuffle left part
      A[done],A[rLeft] = A[rLeft],A[done]
  if left+done<len(A):
      rRight = choice(range(left+done,len(A)))     # shuffle right part
      A[-1-done],A[rRight] = A[rRight],A[-1-done]
  return shuffle(A,left,done+1)                    # recurse
```

output:

```
L = [1, 13, 10, 1, 5, 2, 5, 3]

print(shuffle(L))
[10, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 13]
```

Answer (score -1):

Feels much cleaner to me to just create a new list directly:

```python
def shuffle(array):
    return array[0::2] + array[1::2]

l = [1, 13, 10, 1, 5, 2, 5, 3]
print(shuffle(l))
```

Comment: Rather than use list comprehensions, just use slice notation: `return array[0::2] + array[1::2]`

Comment: Yep, totally much easier to read, updated my answer.